# Select parents for a list of interesting properties in the parent's children

Tags: sql, postgresql, scalikejdbc

I struggled with the title, but let me explain:

Let's say I have two data structures: `Parent` and `Child`. In my (Scala) code, each `Parent` instance has a list of `Child`'s. In the database I have two tables, one for `Parent` and one for `Child`. Each entry in the `Child` table has a value `parentId` that points to its `Parent`.

Table for `Parent`: id int
Table for `Child`: id int, parentId int (foreign key parent.id)

Given a list of `Child` IDs, I want to select each `Parent` (of which there can be none, one or many) that has all these children. Can someone help me out with the query?

UPDATE:

My example didn't cover my use case - sorry. I need to add another field in `Child`: Let's call it `interestingThing`. Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
  id                INT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Child (
  id                INT PRIMARY KEY,
  interestingThing  INT,
  parentId          INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES Parent (id)
);
```

What I need is to find parents that has children with my list of interesting things. Given this data:

```
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO Child VALUES (1, 42, 1);
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (2, 43, 1);
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (3, 44, 1);
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (4, 8, 2);
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (5, 9, 2);
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (6, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (7, 8, 1);
```

I want a query that gets these examples working:

- Given the interesting things (42, 43), I would like to find the parent with id 1.
- Given the interesting things (43, 44), I would like to find the parent with id 1.
- Given the interesting things (8), I would like to find the parent with id 1 and the parent with id 2.
- Given the interesting things (8, 10), I would like to find the parent with id 2.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ARRAY_AGG` function to get an array of all the `interestingThing` for a `parent.id` and use the `@>` (contains) operator:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM parent p 
INNER JOIN child c 
  ON p.id = c.parentId
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(interestingThing) @> '{8}';

┌────┐
│ id │
├────┤
│  1 │
│  2 │
└────┘
(2 rows)
```

---

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM parent p 
INNER JOIN child c 
  ON p.id = c.parentId
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(interestingThing) @> '{8,10}';

┌────┐
│ id │
├────┤
│  2 │
└────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with something like this

```
select  parentId
from    Child
where   id in ( /* your list */ )
group by parentId
having  count(distinct id) = /* your list's length */
```

You will get only the parents that have a count of children equal to the length of your list, only taking into account the desired children and each one only once.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you mean `where parentId in (my list)` there? Also, How can I modify this so that it allows the parent to have more children that are not in my list?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote :) I'll think about a solution for the change you describe

Comment: Thanks. See my updated question though - my first question didn't cover my use case.